# SPFastDeploy "Error deploying to SP App" SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, app

Is there a way how to find out why `SPFastDeploy` fails to upload files?

If I create new project it works without problems, only in my older one there are issues. SharePoint Online

```
Waiting on typescript compile for C:\Users\Jan\Documents\USYK.P01_REGISTRY_OFFICE\OfficeRegistry\OfficeRegistry\Scripts\script\homepage.ts ...
Fast deploying to SP App C:\Users\Jan\Documents\USYK.P01_REGISTRY_OFFICE\OfficeRegistry\OfficeRegistry\Scripts\script\homepage.js ...
Error deploying to SP App C:\Users\Jan\Documents\USYK.P01_REGISTRY_OFFICE\OfficeRegistry\OfficeRegistry\Scripts\script\homepage.js Error: File Not Found.
Fast deploying to SP App C:\Users\Jan\Documents\USYK.P01_REGISTRY_OFFICE\OfficeRegistry\OfficeRegistry\Scripts\script\homepage.ts ...
Error deploying to SP App C:\Users\Jan\Documents\USYK.P01_REGISTRY_OFFICE\OfficeRegistry\OfficeRegistry\Scripts\script\homepage.ts Error: File Not Found.
Fast deploying to SP App C:\Users\Jan\Documents\USYK.P01_REGISTRY_OFFICE\OfficeRegistry\OfficeRegistry\Scripts\script\homepage.js.map ...
Error deploying to SP App C:\Users\Jan\Documents\USYK.P01_REGISTRY_OFFICE\OfficeRegistry\OfficeRegistry\Scripts\script\homepage.js.map Error: File Not Found.
```